# Show that $\int_0^\infty f du = \lim_{⁡n\to\infty}\int_0^n fdu$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Show that if $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[0,\infty)$ then $$\int_0^\infty f du = \lim_{⁡n\to\infty}\int_0^n fdu$$

I tried using Fatou's lemma but I failed to obtain the result. How to go through it?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: what can you say about the functions $f_n:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ defined $f_n = f\chi_{[0,n]}$?

**Added** Note that $\int_0^nfd\mu = \int_{[0,\infty)}f_nd\mu$. It is therefore our goal to show
$$\exists\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,\infty)}f_nd\mu = \int_{[0,\infty)}fd\mu$$
Are you familiar with any tools that might suffice for the task?

Comment: thanks for your comment,Im still a beginner in this course and I study it on my own..so can you elaborate more so that i can understand well how to proceed on this question?

Comment: @nzobo yes, I will, but I'd like to avoid spoiling the exercise for you.

Comment: from that approach, i can retry using monotone convergence theorem. if possible can you send to me a link so that a can learn more?

Comment: @nzobo monotone convergence might work, depending on $f$, but care must be taken. Also, what will you have me link to? (Are you asking for a reference to an elementary measure-theory textbook?)